# Mysql error nested arithmetic in select

Tags: mysql, select, arithmetic-expressions

When i am trying to execute this procedure it is showing an error.

```
USE `metro`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `transaction`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `metro`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `transaction`(
IN amount_p INT,
IN id_in INT,
IN id_out INT,
IN uidd INT
)
BEGIN

DECLARE uide INT;
DECLARE amt INT;
DECLARE NOW_AMT INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT `amount` INTO amt FROM metro.wallet WHERE `uid`=uide;
INSERT INTO metro.transactions(`amount_deducted`,`time`,`station_id_in`,`station_id_out`,`uid`)
VALUES (amount_p,now(),id_in,id_out,uid);
SELECT uidd INTO uide;
SELECT uide;
SET NOW_AMT:=@amt+amount_p;

SELECT amt;
UPDATE metro.wallet SET `uid`=uide,`amount`=NOW_AMT;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

wallet is a table with uid and amount column.

Error code 1048, SQL state 23000: Column 'amount' cannot be null
Line 1, column 1

Execution finished after 0 s, 1 error(s) occurred.

**Execution :**

```
call metro.transaction(112,1,1,1);
```

Comment: One guess is `SET NOW_AMT:=@amt+amount_p;`, the "@amt" references a user variable, not the store proc variable

Comment: Only Update command cann't be executed @DBug

Comment: yes.  If my suspicion is correct, @amt is null, so that would make NOW_AMT null, so when you try to update amount column with NOW_AMT, it is null, so update fails.

Comment: if i does .....UPDATE metro.wallet SET `uid`=uide,`amount`=amount_p;...itworks......when i try UPDATE metro.wallet SET `uid`=uide,`amount`=amt;......it says column amount cann't be null.....i hope this will help u understand my problem

Comment: yes you are right @DBug 'amt' is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps wrap your AMOUNT in a case statement where you can return a default if it is NULL.

```
SELECT case when `amount` is NULL then '' else `amount` END as `amount` INTO amt FROM metro.wallet WHERE `uid`=uide;
```

Comment: if i does .....UPDATE metro.wallet SET `uid`=uide,`amount`=amount_p;...itworks......when i try UPDATE metro.wallet SET `uid`=uide,`amount`=amt;......it says column amount cann't be null.....i hope this will help u understand my problem